# Python loop through rows and then calculate doesn't wok

Tags: python, pandas

What I wanted to do, is to loop through each row.
If the category is "HR contacts" and it's number is smaller than 500 then keep it. Otherwise only keep 500 as part of it.
My code is:

```py
cntByUserNm['keep #'] = np.nan
cntByUserNm['rest #'] = np.nan
for index, row in cntByUserNm.iterrows():
    print(row['Owner Name'], row['source'])
    if row['source'] == 'HR':
        if row['total number'] <= 500:
            row['keep #'] = row['total number']
            row['rest #'] = 0
        else:
            row['keep #'] = 500
            row['rest #'] = row['total number'] - 500
```

But this seems doesn't work, all of the `keep #` and `rest #` still remains `nan`. How to fix this?

````py
for i in range(0, len(cntByUserNm)):
    print(cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['Owner Name'], cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['blizday source'])
    if cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['blizday source'] == mainCat:
        if cntByUserNm.iloc[i][befCnt] <= destiNum:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['keep #'] = cntByUserNm.iloc[i][befCnt]
            cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['rest #'] = 0
        else:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['keep #'] = destiNum
            cntByUserNm.iloc[i]['rest #'] = cntByUserNm.iloc[i][befCnt] - destiNum```
````

Comment: Is it printing everthing from `print(row['Owner Name'], row['source'])`

Comment: @PrabhasKumar  It is printing loop. just after the loop, nothing changed in keep and rest column

Comment: Okay let’s debug this line by line. I’ll give you instructions and you’ll give me the output to find the error. Is that okay?

Comment: @PrabhasKumar each loop and if statement seems working properly, just these '''row['keep #'] = row['total number']''' state won't correct the number in keep and rest column I think

Comment: Add ‘print(“here”)’ right inside the `if row['source'] == 'HR':`

Comment: @PrabhasKumar The character 'here' can output within each loop. and only for the "HR" rows.

Comment: What is cntByUserNm? Numpy array?

Comment: @PrabhasKumar It is a data frame

Comment: You need the index! and iloc(). @wavetitan has answered the question

Comment: @PrabhasKumar I actually tried this before asked this question. It doesn't work either. I updated the question description, can you see that. It is a little bit mess, I just not good at the question format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249947/discussion-between-prabhas-kumar-and-binnnnn5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the **copy** of row of the dataframe, instead of the dataframe itself. Assuming that your row index is continuous (from 0 to len(dataframe)), you can use `.loc` to modify directly on the dataframe.

```py
for index, row in cntByUserNm.iterrows():
    print(row['Owner Name'], row['source'])
    if row['source'] == 'HR':
        if row['total number'] <= 500:
            cntByUserNm.loc[index, 'keep #'] = row['total number']
            cntByUserNm.loc[index, 'rest #'] = 0
        else:
            cntByUserNm.loc[index, 'keep #'] = 500
            cntByUserNm.loc[index, 'rest #'] = row['total number'] - 500
```

If the index is not continuous, you can get the column integer location of `keep #` and `rest #` and use `.iloc`

```py
keep_idx = df.columns.get_loc('keep #')
rest_idx = df.columns.get_loc('rest #')
for index, row in cntByUserNm.iterrows():
    print(row['Owner Name'], row['source'])
    if row['source'] == 'HR':
        if row['total number'] <= 500:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, keep_idx] = row['total number']
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, rest_idx] = 0
        else:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, keep_idx] = 500
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, rest_idx] = row['total number'] - 500
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try your suggest right now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just used iloc in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
keep_idx = df.columns.get_loc('keep #')
rest_idx = df.columns.get_loc('rest #')
for index, row in cntByUserNm.iterrows():
    print(row['Owner Name'], row['source'])
    if row['source'] == 'HR':
        if row['total number'] <= 500:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, keep_idx] = row['total number']
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, rest_idx] = 0
        else:
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, keep_idx] = 500
            cntByUserNm.iloc[index, rest_idx] = row['total number'] - 500
```

Comment: Thank your so much for your kindly help! It seems that the iterrows function is not just as what I though.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas working with vectors is faster. So I suggest:

```
cntByUserNm['keep #'] = np.nan
cntByUserNm['rest #'] = np.nan
mask = (cntByUserNm.loc[:, 'source'] == 'HR') & (cntByUserNm.loc[:, 'total number'] <= 500)
cntByUserNm.loc[mask, 'keep #'] = cntByUserNm.loc[mask, 'total number']
cntByUserNm.loc[mask, 'rest #'] = 0
cntByUserNm.loc[~mask, 'keep #'] = 500
cntByUserNm.loc[~mask, 'rest #'] = cntByUserNm.loc[~mask, 'total number'] - 500
```